# PHP and Oracle using a thin driver

Tags: php, oracle, driver, thin

Is there a thin driver for Oracle available to be used with PHP (for example as an extension)?

I cannot install the OCI driver/client, but need to be able to access an Oracle database.

Comment: "thin" means a driver purely written in php?

Comment: By thin I mean a self contained driver that does not depend on something else to be installed. For instance, Oracle provides a driver for JDBC/Java that doesn't require the official Oracle driver to be installed. This is very lightweight and easy to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the problem with installing the OCI driver ?
The [InstantClient](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/notes/technote_php_instant.html) version simply requires an unzip and setting a couple of environment variables.

The other option is exposing the database functionality through web services. 11g includes an inbuilt HTTP server.

Comment: I was hoping to find a drop-in solution that didn't require system changes. Mainly to simplify deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle released a jdbc driver written only in java, but (afaik) without the source code, so I doubt they will release a php (source code) driver. And never heard of an attempt by someone else.

But another question: "(for example as an extension)" You would be able to install an extension but not the oci8 extension?

Comment: Wouldn't the OCI8 extension require the installation of the Oracle driver?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "thin" Oracle driver in PHP.  You always need an external client library such as Oracle Instant Client - which is really easy to install.
Check http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/php/pdf/underground-php-oracle-manual.pdf

(Also, Oracle has RPMs of PHP and Instant Client that can be used on RH Linux.)